# Lombok Builder with defaults in Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data, lombok

I have the following (simplified) class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor // @Builder creates the all-args version but I need this one elsewhere.
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE) // Having @NoArgsConstructor disables the @AllArgsConstructor needed by @Builder unless I have this explicitly applied
public class MyClass {

  // ...
  @Builder.Default
  private String foo = "Some Default Value"
  // ...

}
```

This works fine in the general case, but a problem comes about when this Entity gets built by Spring (specifically Spring Data Repository in response to a REST request to create it).  Spring sees the all-args constructor and uses it, setting a null value for foo (in this case it wasn't set in the POST data) and I end up with a null value for foo instead of the expected `"Some Default Value"`.  The `@Builder.Default`.

It does not work to simply create the setter and prevent nulls.  I could write out the AllArgsConstructor explicitly, but that (somewhat) defeats the purpose of Lombok to some extent.  Not a horrible solution, but not ideal.

Can anyone think of any workarounds for this?

Comment: Did you try changing AccessType. Try with this `@AccessType(AccessTpe.FIELD)` on the class

Comment: I can't see how that would work. AccessType is about how the data layer gets the values that are to be persisted, right?  Either directly via the field or through an accessor.  Also, the default is already field access, so this wouldn't even be a change, I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can specify default values with the non-lombok default values. I haven't tried it with this particular case, but its worth a shot.

@Value("#{prop['my.property'] ?: 12345}")

Maybe you should try using the RequiredArgs Constructor which only specifies a constructor that uses "one argument per final / non-null field" and that won't override the var.

https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor

Comment: The Builder annotation requires an AllArgsConstructor regardless.  And Spring seems to be eager in choosing the all-args version over any other version.

Which Value annotation is that?  The Lombok one can't be applied to a property, and I don't think the Spring one would do any good here.  It'll set the default value to something that's not known at design time, but isn't going to override the behavior of the all-args constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this using a PrePersist annotation in my model class.  With the PrePersist I can make sure that null values get their defaults set regardless of when they were set to null, or by whom.  Not truly a fix for this, but something I should probably be doing anyway so it's an acceptable workaround.